# Fill a dictionnary from a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary

Dears,

Your support please to have the below target output..

The input is a list in which the number whith four digits (exp : '1368', , '1568', '1768') should b the key of output dictionary, and the number with one digit which follow the 4 digits numbers should be the values of those keys like below.

*exp :*

**INPUT :**
['1368', '1', '1368', '3', '1568', '1', '1568', '3', '1568', '2', '1768', '3', '1768', '2', '2368', '1', '2368', '3', '2368', '2']

**OUTPUT**
{'1368' :['1', '3'], '1568' :['1', '3','2'], '1768' :['3','2'], '2368' :['1','3','2'] }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
output = {}
for key in iterator:=iter(input):
   value = next(iterator)
   output.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

But I apologize - this is a "pythonism" - as we in Python tend to avoid having to deal with explicit indexes for sequences. There is no harm in the more readable:

```
output = {}
for index in range(0, len(input), 2):
   key, value = input[i], input[i+1]
   output.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

The  "setdefault" method on the other hand is a valid "pythonism" and is equivalent to "if this key already exists in the dicionary, return it, otherwise, set it to this new value (the second argument), and return it΅ - and it avoids the need for an "if" statement and an additional line.